# How to fix Github pages not recognizing files

Tags: python, github, flask, web

Why aren't my files working correctly when I upload them into GitHub? They work fine in the IDE with local flask.
Although the files only worked in visual code if the structure is something like this.

your_project/
static/
main.css
noscript.css
templates/
index.html
images/
image1.jpg
image2.png
..etc

GitHub repo is: https://github.com/ciripmav/tester.git
the site: https://ciripmav.github.io/Wouldr/

would appreciate any help.

I tried taking the index.html out but it made it worse since, beforehand it needed to be in a folder named templates. When the github would actually find my index ( from me manually entering it in url ) it wouldn't implement the css styling. I tried uploading through github desktop and on the website. I spent a lot of time debugging this so i feel it a waste not to be able to see it live.

Answer (score -3):

revisit site by rebooting your system or open task manager and end some background tasks of your browser this will help to reboot the browser you are using.

Comment: How does rebooting your computer do anything to Github Pages?